# Jenkins Shared Library: Function with single required String parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-shared-libraries

I have a shared library for a project specific Jenkins Setup.

One of my files in `vars/gradle.groovy` looks as follows:

```
/**
 * simple wrapper around the ./gradlew command in a repository.
 *
 *
 * @param command : the gradle command that will be executed.
 *
 * @return nothing, except for status codes.
 */
void call(String command) {
    sh "./gradlew ${command}"
}

return this
```

When I try to call it from my actual project code (declarative Jenkinsfile)
like this:

```
...
stage('Gradle Build + Docker Build (against remote DB)') {
    steps {
        gradle "-PtestEnv=stage --continue build"
    }
}
...
```

I get the following error:

```
WorkflowScript: 97: Step does not take a single required parameter - use named parameters instead @ line 97, column 17.
                   gradle "-PtestEnv=stage --continue build"
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Other functions use named parameters, and they work out of the box.

But in this case I would prefer a simple `String` parameter to make the interface of the method as convenient as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try this?: gradle command:"-PtestEnv=stage --continue build"

Comment: Similar issue as I would have expected:

`WorkflowScript: 118: Invalid parameter "command", did you mean "tasks"? @ line 118, column 24. gradle command: "-PtestEnv=stage --continue testResourceIntegration"`

Comment: Try wrapping your `gradle` method call inside a `script {}` block. That is required anyway for global var method invokes and may be your only issue.